# PHP: check datetime to see if it's coming up

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime

I've getting a DATETIME from the database and I need to be able to check to see whether or not that date is within 30 days from now.

```
$renewal_date = $row['renewal_date'];
$current_time = new DateTime();
$interval = $renewal_date->diff($current_time);
```

That ain't workin' for me.

Comment: Is `$renewal_date` a DateTime object?

Comment: strtotime is a good place to start I think http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: That doesn't make it a PHP DateTime object. Do `var_dump($renewal_date);` to see.

Comment: check whether $renewal_date and $current_time are in same format...???(like 'mm-dd-yy' or 'yy-dd-mm')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$renewal_date = new DateTime($row['renewal_date']);
$cutoff= new DateTime('+31 days 00:00');


if ($renewal_date < $cutoff && $renewal_date >= new DateTime)
    echo 'Renewal Time!';
else
    echo 'All OK!';
```

Remove the && condition if you want to show renewal for dates in the past

Comment: I'm starting to notice a flaw ... the chances of a CRON job being able to lang exactly on "30 days" from now it slim to none. So how would I be able to catch that renewal within reason?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? I upated my answer so that it will always be midnight of 30th day. So if you run your cron every day it will always check fine. remember it is < not ==

Comment: Yeah, what you did above is exactly what I needed!

Comment: +1 Ah! now I see it. `DateTime`class really exists! but be careful, is 5.2+ compatible...

Answer (score 0):

```
$renewal_date = strtotime($renewal_date); // maybe need it depending of sql format of date

if (abs($renewal_date - time()) < 86400*30)
{
    echo 'less than 30 days from now';
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**

`abs($renewal_date - time())` gives a lapsus of time from now (`time()`) that it is supposed to refer to future. indeed the condition could to serve to past periods too...

`< 86400*30` says that the lapsus must be inferior to 30 days...

That were my 2 cents to the cause :)

Comment: Seconds in a day. A bad way of doing this comparison IMO.

Comment: @sachleen why it is? 30days=86400secs*30 exactly.

Comment: Because it's not obvious what's going on from reading it. Also [leap second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Comment: Yeah, but @sachleen you haven't exactly given an answer to how to find out if the "renewal_date" is 30 days of less then NOW

Comment: @sachleen I know what are you saying I am working with more fine exactitude, but question clearly shows that it is a simple comparison. 30 days...

Comment: @dcolumbus Kris did a pretty good job of that. :) NomikOS, generally speaking, time is a very tricky thing to work with and if you're not careful, little things can mess you up. I find it a good idea to use the language features or a popular library for time calculations. Of course, you could decide things like leap seconds don't matter in this case, and that would be acceptable.

Comment: @sachleen totally agreed. totally agreed. server/client time differences count too. cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that $row['renewal_date'] is a DateTime object?

My impression is that this is a value that you take from a database rather than a DateTime object.

Try a var_dump($renewal_date) and if this is a string containing a date value, you should use something like:

```
$renewal_date = new DateTime ($row['renewal_date']);
$current_time = new DateTime();
$interval = $renewal_date->diff($current_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$renewal_date` is not a PHP [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object. You can do `var_dump($renewal_date);` to verify this.

Check out the [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) manual for examples. You'll want to convert your date to a DateTime object using something like this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($renewal_date);
```

Then it should work.